# Cannot create Alloy Controller in Appcelerator Studio

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I got an error after updating Appcelerator studio from 4.0.0 GA to 5.2.2 GA. Now i can no longer create allot controller because this error shows up;

> C:\Users\dummy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appcelerator\node_modules\update-notifier\node_modules\latest-version\node_modules\package-json\node_modules\got\index.js:2
>   const EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter; ^^^^^
>   SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
>       at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
>       at require (module.js:384:17)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\dummy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appcelerator\node_modules\update-notifier\node_modules\latest-version\node_modules\package-json\index.js:3:11)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)

Does anybody know to solve it? Any help will be deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Post some code so that we can guide you.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
```

change to:

```
var EventEmitter = (require('events')).EventEmitter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalled and install new Appcelerator was the only option for me.